# Files not found on Azure Paas

Tags: azure, paas

We have a solution installed on Azure Paas. In the logs we have next errors:

```
Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Message: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\sitecore\shell\client\sitecore\speak\ribbon\controls\largebutton\largebutton.js'.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Pipelines.ResolveScript.Controls.LoadFile(ResolveScriptArgs args, String fileName)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Pipelines.ResolveScript.Controls.Process(ResolveScriptArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeli ne.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Data.PipelineHost.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Scripts.ScriptHandler.DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Scripts.ScriptHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)","cms-Prod"
```

And Experience Editor or other Sitecore Application doesn't work. A workaround is to restart the app service and the Experience Editor will work fine.

Another example is:

```
Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Message: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\sitecore\default.aspx'.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.Web.Hosting.MapPathBasedVirtualFile.Open()
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at Sitecore.DependencyInjection.AutowiredPageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()","cms-Prod"
"7/21/2021, 12:46:25.151 PM","25864 12:46:25 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127824/discussion-on-question-by-vlad-iobagiu-files-not-found-on-azure-paas).